# Problem: spree shows basic auth, users accounts is not worked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, spree-auth-devise

I am working with ready spree shop site. It is worked fine on production deploy, from this source code tree. But in development it asks basic auth. Database is backup form production. Users account which is worked on production are not helps pass this basic auth. It looks slike this:

[image]

Rails console:

> 192.168.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2020:14:52:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 401 - 0.0271

Nginx log:

> 192.168.0.1 - - [28/Jan/2020:17:52:28 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"

Nginx error log is empty

What is this? How to run it properly? How to find and fix this feature or oprion? What "Beta access" string from dialog window on screen is about? What can I do to make situation more clear?

Comment: Have you tried a directory search for the string "Beta Access"?  That likely is being generated by the code you are looking for.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I tried but some confision was, may be with folder to search or typo with text typed from screen. Actually your comment make me try again (also in gems) so now it clear. May be you copy your comment to ticket and I will add what I found to it. So I can accept it. How about?

Comment: Well no, my comment still doesn't provide the answer, it just helps you find the source.  If you have the fix then I would post that as the answer and you can accept your answer later on.